# No possibility of default lambda in class template

Tags: c++, templates

I've found out that one cannot create a working template class that has a default nothing-doing `std::function` in it, however if we create non-template class, there is no problem with the default value. Default lambda has no captures. Please see:

```
struct Dump {
    function<void(bool)> f = [](bool) {};
};

int main() {
    Dump a;
    a.f(true);
}
```

The above example works, however when parameterized (even parameter is not used)

```
template <class T>
struct Dump {
    function<void(bool)> f = [](bool) {};
};


int main() {
    Dump<bool> a;
    a.f(true);
}
```

during compilation get an error:

```
error: conversion from 'Dump<bool>::__lambda0' to non-scalar type 'std::function<void(bool)>' requested
note: synthesized method 'constexpr Dump<bool>::Dump()' first required here
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? `gcc-8` and `clang` both happily accept the second snippet.

Comment: Adding a default constructor that does the same, i.e. f = [](bool){}; makes the compiler accept it, but still I can't understand what's happening here - why it is not accepted in default initialization?

Comment: @lubgr gcc-4.8.2

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  I can get it to compile with all versions of clang 4.9.1 or higher (except 5.1) on godbolt.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 and gcc 7.3 works fine here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that older versions of compilers (close to when C++ 11 introduced these features) have some issues compiling this code, but they look like compiler bugs. You can play with different compiler versions [here](https://godbolt.org/g/4T11mc).

- `clang` has no problems with the code since version `3.4.1` (around the time C++ 11 became a thing).
- `gcc` gives the error you show in versions `4.7.1` to `4.9.0`, compiles it just fine in `4.9.1` to `4.9.4`, gets an internal compiler error (!) in `5.1` and apparently has no problem with it afterwards.
- `icc` version `13.0.1` rejects the initializer altogether, `16.0.1` and later has no problem.
- `MSVC` only has two versions available and starts from the 2015 version but eats the syntax without problems.

So the solution for you would be to either avoid default-initialization of `std::function` with lambdas or simply use a more recent compiler. The latter will probably save you a lot of pain in the long run.